# how to echo xml file in php by using simpleXML?

Tags: php, simplexml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<note>
<to>George</to>
<from>John</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget the meeting!</body>
</note>
```

how to use php to echo xml information

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)

Comment: If you are having a particular issue with SimpleXML post that. If not this is too broad, and a dup.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get your XML File. Then just echo what you want. Example:

```
$file = file_get_contents('http://example.com/rss');
echo $file;
```

Comment: This has no relation to SimpleXML. `by using simpleXML`.